# An exception is being raised when testing websocket with POSTMAN

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

I am implementing web sockets in my Django Project with channels library. When an object is created, name of that object should be sent to a consumer with group name test_consumer_group_1.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField("Employee")
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        data = {"current_obj":self.name}
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            "test_consumer_group_1",{
                'type':'send_notification',
                'value':json.dumps(data)
            }
    )
```

This is the code of my consumer:

```
class TestConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name="test_consumer"
        self.room_group_name = "test_consumer_group_1"
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.channel_name, 
            self.room_group_name
        )
        self.accept()
        print('connected..')
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'status':'connected'}))

    def recieve(self, text_data):
        print(text_data)

    def disconnect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('disconnected')

    def send_notification(self, event):
        print("send_notification called")
        print(event)
```

But it gives following error when testing the websocket API with POSTMAN:

```
 raise TypeError(self.invalid_name_error.format("Group", name))
TypeError: Group name must be a valid unicode string with length < 100 containing only ASCII alphanumerics, hyphens, underscores, or periods, not specific.be2251de4bb647c1988845bd460d6971!564c92a792634237bcdba63290554557
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/test/ [127.0.0.1:35480]
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `channel_name` attribute of the `WebsocketConsumer` to get the channel name and use it while adding channel to the group so:

```py
class TestConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = "test_consumer"
        self.room_group_name = "test_consumer_group_1"
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.channel_name,
            self.room_group_name
        )
        self.accept()
        print('connected..')
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'status': 'connected'}))

    def receive(self, text_data):
        print(text_data)

    def disconnect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('disconnected')
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def send_notification(self, event):
        print("send_notification called")
        print(event)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))
```